# how to set two navbar in single webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css

how to set two navbar in webpage one is static and other one is fixed the static navbar will be disappear when we scrolled down the page and fixed navbar will come on it's place for e.g you can see this link : [http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto/5.4.0/index-corporate-8.html](http://how%20to%20set%20two%20navbar%20in%20webpage%20one%20is%20static%20and%20other%20one%20is%20fixed%20the%20static%20navbar%20will%20be%20disappear%20when%20we%20scrolled%20down%20the%20page%20and%20fixed%20navbar%20will%20come%20on%20it's%20place%20for%20e.g%20you%20can%20see%20this%20link%20:%20http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto/5.4.0/index-corporate-8.html)

Comment: you need to maintain navbar display content based on jquery

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you...Please find fiddler [here](http://jsfiddle.net/namuol/Uaa3U/)

Js part

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav-wrapper').height($("#nav").height());

    $('#nav').affix({
        offset: { top: $('#nav').offset().top }
    });
});
```

css part

```
#nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%
}

#nav > .navbar-inner {
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0;
}
```

HTML part

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- micro hero unit-->
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="well">
                <h1> Some page title </h1>
                <p> This is a website. </p>
                <p> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Tell me more</a> </p>
            </div>
            <!-- well -->
        </div>
        <!-- span12 -->
    </div> <!-- row -->
</div>
<div id="nav-wrapper">
    <div id="nav" class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="span12">
                    <a class="brand" href="#">My Brand</a>
                    <span class="navbar-text">
                    This is my navbar.
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- container -->
        </div> <!-- navbar-inner -->
    </div> <!-- navbar -->
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="span3">
        <h2>some lorem ipsum for scrolling:</h2>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap then there is class defined to do this particular function but on single nav bar. 
if not then you need to handle it single nav bar with Jquery or Jscript